# iOS UIAutomation UIAElement.isVisible() throwing stale response?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to use isVisible() within a loop to create a waitForElement type of a function for my iOS UIAutomation. When I try to use the following code, it fails while waiting for an element when a new screen pops up. The element is clearly there because if I do a delay(2) before tapping the element it works perfectly fine. How is everyone else accomplishing this, because I am at a loss...

Here's the waitForElement code that I am using:

```
function waitForElement(element, timeout, step) {
        if (step == null) {
                step = 0.5;
        }

        if (timeout == null) {
            timeout = 10;
        }

        var stop = timeout/step;

        for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
                if (element.isVisible()) {
                        return;
                }
                target.delay(step);
        }
        element.logElement();
        throw("Not visible");
}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I'm looking to implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an 'element' object to this function. When the function starts, your 'element' object has *isVisible* property *false* or when there is no such object on the screen you are passing *[object UIAElement Nil]*. Trying to get the property *isVisible* for this kind of object at any time will always return *false*.

If you want this function to work, you need to pass 'element' as an object into your function.
So instead of

```
if (element.isVisible())
```

you need to get element object first and try to get isVisible() property.

```
if (target.manWindow().elements()[0].isVisible())
```

After this change there will be no need to pass 'element' object since this function will work only with one element.

To make this function to work with any element, you need to pass not an 'element' object but the function that returns 'element' object you want to check.
This is an example:

```
var target = ...;
var mainWindow = ...;

//function that returns firstObject
var firstElement = function()
{
return mainWindow.elements()[0];
}
//function that returns secondObject
var secondElement = function()
{
return mainWindow.elements()[1];
}
```

//this is what you need to change in your 'wait' function. Change

```
if (element.isVisible())
```

with

```
if (element().isVisible())
```

Example of your function call:

```
waitForElement(firstElement, 10, 1);
waitForElement(secondElement, 10, 1);
```

NOTE: if you will call your *waitForElement* function with **firstElement()** - function will fail with the same error. This makes your tests more complicated but it works.